# Next Js showing index of build folder when using serve

Tags: reactjs, next.js

i was trying to run build folder of next js , in react js when i run `serve build` it works perfectly. but in next js it just shows plain index of files in build folder..

[image]

What should i do to get proper results rather than index?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`serve`](https://github.com/vercel/serve) only supports serving a static build of a site. So to build a static site in next.js you need to edit your `package.json` file like that:

```
"scripts": {
  "build": "next build && next export"
}
```

Then you can try `npm run build` to generate the static build in the `out` folder which you can serve easily via `serve out` command.

Quoting from nextjs site @ https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/static-html-export :

> `next export` allows you to export your Next.js application to static HTML, which can be run standalone without the need of a Node.js server. It is recommended to only use `next export` if you don't need any of the unsupported features requiring a server.

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks Sahil , if anyone using this make sure to update loader to akamai in next.config.js